# Feeling defeated: APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset

Tags: python, binance

I am following the latest specifications on `step_size` and `tick_size` according to binance’s exchange info endpoint for BTCUSDT:

```
"BTCUSDT": {
      "step_size": "0.00001",
      "tick_size": "0.01"
   },
```

And even doing everything according to the documentation, I am still getting the following error:

```
APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
```

I really am out of options. I’ve been creating trading bots with Binance API since 2020 and I have never found a clear solution to this problem. Only temporary fixes that for whatever reason end up failing, eventually, even if the exchange info data has not changed.

These are the functions I currently use to truncate price and quantity before creating the binance order (which do work for many other pairs like VETUSDT):

```
def __get_trimmed_quantity(self, quantity):
    self.logger.log("untrimmed qty: ", quantity)
    quantity_dec = Decimal(str(quantity))
    step_size_dec = Decimal(str(self.step_size))
    trimmed_quantity_dec = quantity_dec.quantize(step_size_dec)
    trimmed_quantity = float(trimmed_quantity_dec)
    return trimmed_quantity

def __get_trimmed_price(self, price):
    self.logger.log("untrimmed price: ", price)
    price_dec = Decimal(str(price))
    tick_size_dec = Decimal(str(self.tick_size))
    trimmed_price_dec = price_dec.quantize(tick_size_dec)
    trimmed_price = float(trimmed_price_dec)
    return trimmed_price
```

And here you can see the logs that lead up to the error. You can verify that the order has the proper truncated price and quantity.

```
untrimmed qty:  0.28760622
untrimmed price:  26193.02
Order to create (binance):  {'side': 'SELL', 'positionSide': 'SHORT', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'quantity': 0.28761, 'price': 26193.02, 'newClientOrderId': '35021e7298b34c838f0b64e291ead9e1'}
__create_order_to_open_position: Binance order creation failed:  APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
```

All I want is the order to go through. I’ll do whatever you tell me. Give me a function I can throw a quantity and price at and it will spit out the proper truncated values. I don’t care how it’s done. I just want it to work. Please.

Can anybody spot what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong precisions!

FUTURES API has its own set of precisions which differ from SPOT trading.

So for FUTURES, BTCUSDT is currently:

step_size:  0.001
tick_size:  0.1